# Android studio wont create binding classes

Tags: android-databinding

I have an android application that makes use of data binding functionalities with android studio 4.1.1
It compiles ok, and I can see generated classes in app/build/generated directory.
the generated DataBuildMapperImpl is OK as well and references the binding classes.
i have three binding classes, one for main activity, and two for Fragments

Now, if I try to create a new Fragment ( using Studio new Helper), it simply does not create the Binding classes, hence the code to bind the layout does not compile

Any idea of the problem or how i could investigate e.g lookin at Build traces / log ?

Here is the BlankFragment layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blank"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and the Fragment code

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.christophe.fretboard.databinding.FragmentBlankBinding


class BlankFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentBlankBinding>(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late and you probably figured it out by the time but I'll still give an answer for people in future.

If you want Android Studio to generate data binding classes you should encapsulate your layout with `layout` tag just like this:
`<layout>// your FrameLayout goes here <\layout>`
End if your layout's name is fragment_example it's binding class' name will be ExampleFragmentBinding.

Comment: Thank you very much Ibrahim,I had seen it in the binding codelab, but the prerequisite is not that clear in the ref doc. It did drive me mad for a while ..